# JAXB Unmarshall not standard xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshall this XML:

```
<result>
    <Contacts>
        <row nb="1">
            <PK val="First Name">JeanValJean</PK>
            <PK val="Last Name">Dupont</PK>
        </row>
    </Contacts>
</result>
```

I am trying to unmarshall it this way:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Result {

    @XmlElement(name = "Contacts")
    private Contacts contacts;
```

then:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contacts {

    @XmlElement(name = "row")
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Contacts() {}
    public Contacts(Collection<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts.addAll(contacts);
    }

    public Contacts add(Contact contact) {
        contact.setNb(contacts.size() + 1);
        contacts.add(contact);
        return this;
    }
```

then (**maybe the error is here - matching between PK?**):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contact {

@XmlAttribute
private int nb = 0;

@XmlElement(name = "PK")
private Field firstName = new Field("First Name");

@XmlElement(name = "PK")
private Field lastName = new Field("Last Name");
```

then:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PK")
public class Field {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "val")
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;
```

When I am trying to unmarshall it I get null name value.

How to make it work? 
How to simplify it?

Comment: You also seem to have a mismatch between the "no"  attribute of class Contact, and the corresponding "nb" attribute of the XML (inside the "row" tag)

Comment: thank you i update the question without this typo error.

Comment: First, I think there is no error in your code. Why it can't works, it is due to your xml content. Please take a look,  Why flag ends with <result>, not </result>?